# Chef 'wlp' cookbook throwing 404 error when trying to download Liberty

Tags: websphere, chef-infra, websphere-liberty

I'm thinking that the url 'used to be available' here, but now, due to something involved in accepting the license agreement, it no longer is:

https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/liberty-profile-using-non-eclipse-environments/wlp-developers-runtime-8.5.5.4.jar

Here is the cookbook page: https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/wlp/versions/0.2.2

The error:

```
ec2-54-67-111-140.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com Error executing action create on 
resource 'remote_file[/var/chef/cache/wlp-developers-runtime-8.5.5.4.jar]' 
ec2-54-67-111-140.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com 
ec2-54-67-111-140.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com 
ec2-54-67-111-140.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com 
ec2-54-67-111-140.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com Net::HTTPServerException 
ec2-54-67-111-140.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com ------------------------ 
ec2-54-67-111-140.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com 404 "Not Found" 
ec2-54-67-111-140.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com 
ec2-54-67-111-140.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

my chef role

```
{"name":"websphere",
  "default_attributes" : {
   "wlp" : {
     "archive" : {
       "accept_license" : true,
       "base_url" : "https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/liberty-profile-using-non-eclipse-environments"    
      }
   },
  "java" : { 
   "install_flavor" : "oracle", 
   "jdk_version" : "7", 
   "oracle" : { 
     "accept_oracle_download_terms" : true 
   } 
 } 
},
"run_list":[
 "recipe[chef-client]",
 "recipe[application_wlp]",
 "recipe[wlp]"
]
 }
```

I've inspected the output from wlp cookbook default.rb:

```
p "*"25 
p node[:wlp][:archive][:base_url] 
p "*"25 #<> URL location of the runtime archive. 
default[:wlp][:archive][:runtime][:url] = "#{node[:wlp][:archive][:base_url]}/wlp-developers-runtime-8.5.5.4.jar"
p ""25 p default[:wlp][:archive][:runtime][:url] 
p ""*25

ec2-54-67-111-140.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com 
"*******" 
ec2-54-67-111-140.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com   "https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/liberty-profile-using-non-eclipse-environments" ec2-54-67-    111-140.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com 
"*******" 
ec2-54-67-111-140.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com 
"*******" 
ec2-54-67-111-140.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com "https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/liberty-profile-using-non-eclipse-environments/wlp-developers-runtime-8.5.5.4.jar" ec2-54-67-111-140.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Visiting that last url in a browser does indeed give a 404 error. How can Chef download this jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the source site does not allow direct download anymore you have to download it yourself and host it somewhere on an http server.

Then use this as the source url by overriding the `default[:wlp][:archive][:base][:url]`in your role where you already have the url toward it:

```
{"name":"websphere",
  "default_attributes" : {
   "wlp" : {
     "archive" : {
       "accept_license" : true,
       "base_url" : "https://<path to your internal hosting server>"    
      }
   },
  "java" : { 
   "install_flavor" : "oracle", 
   "jdk_version" : "7", 
   "oracle" : { 
     "accept_oracle_download_terms" : true 
   }
 } 
},
"run_list":[
 "recipe[chef-client]",
 "recipe[application_wlp]",
 "recipe[wlp]"
]
}
```